# What can ECG DC level be?

Tags: analog, biopotential

In ECG signal, to what DC level should i expect? Can it be 3V, at least from time to time?

Alternatively, what would be decent input voltage range for the instrumental amplifier for ECG stage?

Comment: Try grounding the person via a separate electrode? If you let them float with respect to your circuit ground, and your amplifier impedance is high, there could easily be 100 V of 50 Hz on the person, plus any amount of DC.

Comment: Yes, but still, say if it's not DC, but like 0.1Hz wave, can it reach 3V or so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This discussion is on DIFFERENTIAL ECG signals.  There can be common mode signals of volts.

Output DC levels are zero, as even the widest ECG high pass filters at 0.05 Hz.  On the input, that's going to depend on electrode offsets, skin preparation, and other electrode attachment factors.  I always allow for at least 150 mV.

That's the target for a working ECG.  The clinical units are built to survive relatively low frequency transients of hundreds to thousands of volts in the event of defibrillation.

When you see large low freq offsets in ECG output, you're usually talking about bad things, like fibrillation, and I'd put possible offsets at around the magnitude of the QRS complex.

As for common mode signals, [Winter and Webster, 1983 (link to pdf)](http://www.elastyc.unimore.it/fonda/ELBIOM/Reduction%20of%20Interference%20Due%20to%20Common%20Mode%20Voltage%20in%20Biopotential%20Amplifiers.pdf) say it can be as small as a few millivolts if the subject is well grounded, and reach 20V if the subject is holding a power cord.  It can, of course, be reduced if using driven-leg techniques [(link to pdf)](https://ay14-15.moodle.wisc.edu/prod/pluginfile.php/82829/mod_resource/content/2/Driven-Right-Leg%20Circuit%20Design.pdf), but that won't work at 20V because of amplifier saturation.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum -  edited to include real numbers for common mode signals

Comment: Thank you! What input filter would you recommend? I see many different options throughout the web, LPF, BPF, HPF, with all kinds of resistors and capacitors, and it looks that for everyone something else works, and except good CMRR no one knows, how to decide the input stage.

Comment: I recommend NO input filter, but an instrumentation amp that can handle the common mode voltage, then a reasonable gain so as not to saturate, followed by an active 2-pole HP filter at about 0.5Hz, , more gain, and a low pass filter with even more gain.

Comment: Thanks again! Why small gain on the first stage?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum -- if you have a DC difference of 200 mV on your electrodes, it doesn't take too much amplification to saturate it, depending on where your rails are.  A gain of 20 would give you 4 volts out.  So, multiply it up, then filter out the DC offset with a high pass filter, and multiply it again.  You should use low offset voltage op amps when you have big gain stages

Comment: Ok, but why not filtering DC out straight on the input?

Comment: You could, but unless you treat both inputs EXACTLY the same, you could turn common mode noise (good) into differential noise (bad).  Capacitor tolerance is pretty low, so I like to get signals into the instrumentation amp as directly as possible, get rid of the CM noise with a super CMRR, and then do any processing I need to do.  In actuality, my pref of late is to use a modest gain instrumentation amp, a light low-pass filter, and then sample w/ an (oversampling) sigma delta converter at 24 bits.

Comment: Have you ever had to calibrate the differential stage?

Comment: No, but the typical method is to use a small square wave.

Comment: Sure, but the point is, that good design that doesn't require calibration is possible, right?

Comment: Yes, its more of a verification that nothing went wrong than anything else.  IA gain is usually set by one resistor, and if you need a very accurate gain, you can use a high tolerance resistor.  A "reality check" can be good to build in, though.  Also, it would depend on who you need to prove accurate calibration to, and how hard they are to convince.

Answer (score 3):

> In ECG signal, to what DC level should i expect?

With usual ECG electrode chemistry one can expect up to about 300 mV DC offset. Which is pretty big compared to the ECG signal at ~1 mV AC.

> Can it be 3V, at least from time to time?

It depends. It could happen when the ECG leads are off, and you do DC lead-off detection. A signal with so much DC offset would be noise only and contains no usable ECG.

You probably want to use AC coupling, or work with a high pass filter to remove the DC offset.